# php json_encode not working properly (add 0 in each row)

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a mysql table which has only 1 column "c_name".
When i echo rows of this table (json_encoded), it gives me this  -
`[{"0":"Apparel, Textiles & Accessories","c_name":"Apparel, Textiles & Accessories"},{"0":"Auto & Transportation","c_name":"Auto & Transportation"},{"0":"Electronics","c_name":"Electronics"},{"0":"Machinery, Industrial Parts & Tools","c_name":"Machinery, Industrial Parts & Tools"},{"0":"Gifts, Sports & Toys","c_name":"Gifts, Sports & Toys"}]`

Why is 0 coming in each and every row ?
I don't want it.

Here's my code -

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM categories";
$r=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$rows = array();
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    // Fetch one and one row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);

    //Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else
{
    echo "Umm... Some internal error.";
}
```

Any help ?

Thanks,

Comment: We can't help you with code we cannot see. But I assure you `json_encode` is working properly ([`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)); you need to look at what it is you're passing *into* it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of you use `->fetch()` method of your SQL object. This method returns two values (FETCH_ROW and FETCH_ASSOC). Try to print_r() your variable before json_encode and you'll see this.

Or provide your code from SQL query to json_encode.

Replaice your `mysqli_fetch_array` with `mysqli_fetch_row` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($r))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the second argument of **mysqli_fetch_array()** to **MYSQLI_ASSOC**:

```
// Fetch one and one row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

The default is **MYSQLI_BOTH**, which returns both numeric indexes and named indexes.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php